# Containstable rank returns different score for identical data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005 engine, I have a table that happens to have duplicate data in it.

The duplicate data is binary same when checking the checksum value, however, `containstable` happens to be ranking the data differently.  Out of my sample data of 11 rows, there are three distinct different ranks.

```
Checksum    Data                   Rank 
464359846   <My Data Results>   194 
464359846   <My Data Results>   **194** 
464359846   <My Data Results>   **259**
464359846   <My Data Results>   259 
464359846   <My Data Results>   194 
464359846   <My Data Results>   259 
464359846   <My Data Results>   194 
464359846   <My Data Results>   194 
464359846   <My Data Results>   194 
464359846   <My Data Results>   194 
464359846   <My Data Results>   **388**
```

Any explanation on why these 11 records would not have the exact same rank since they are the same?

SQL Query:

```
select  
     'Checksum' = checksum('sha1',convert(varchar(max),col_A)),
    col_A
    KeyTbl.Rank
from  dbo.table1 a  
join containstable(table1, col_A, '"term1" and "term2"') as keytbl  
    on a.Id = keytbl.[key]  
where
    a.controlNum = 'i03898385'
```

Comment: can you show your query please ??